# Multiple Joins in a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a one-to-many between table A and B, and again between table B and C.  I need to list all records in table B, along with their parent from table A, and the sum() of a particular field in C.  How can I do this?

I think it is something like:

```
SELECT A.fldlist, 
       B.fldlist, 
       SUM(C.field)
  FROM A 
  INNER JOIN B ON A.key = b.FK 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C on B.key = C.FK
  GROUP BY B.field
```

Any ideas?  Much appreciated...

Comment: You're missing `a.fldlist` in the GROUP BY - otherwise looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by all fields in A and B you can always do this

```
With tmp as
(
   SELECT c.FK, SUM(C.field) as field
   FROM C
   GROUP BY c.FK
)
SELECT A.*, B.*, tmp.FK, tmp.field
FROM   A 
       INNER JOIN B ON A.key = b.FK
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp ON b.key = tmp.FK
```

Comment: Thanks clyc.  How do I 'set x' to a value though?  I tried inserting it verbatim into your select clause, and could do that for the first occurrence but not the second...

Comment: x is an alias so you're not setting it to a value. you can always rename the x to tmp

Comment: Thanks clyc.  That was awesome.

Comment: I think some of Kim's confusion over x/tmp may be the fact that you're referencing `c.FK, c.field` in your main SELECT where it should be `tmp.FK, tmp.field`

Answer (score 5):

Close, but you'll need to group by all the non-aggregate columns in your SELECT.

```
SELECT A.fldlist, 
       B.fldlist, 
       SUM(C.field)
  FROM A 
  INNER JOIN B ON A.key = b.FK 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C on B.key = C.FK
  GROUP BY A.fldlist, B.fldlist
```

Comment: Thanks Joe.  What if my fieldlist is very long?  In this case, it's actually all fields from both table A and B.

Comment: You'll need to group by all the fields in the select list that are not part of an aggregate function like "sum".

Comment: @Kim: You've found clyc's answer to your question.